# Extract DIV from XHTML with simpleHTMLDom and then print out

Tags: simpledom

Task - scrape content inside a DIV tag with an ID and then return the XHTML.
I am using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser'

Example simplified code:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<h1>Head</h1>
<div class="page">
<div id="content">
<h2>Section head</h2>
<p>Text</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the content OK with:

```
$content = $html->find('#content');
```

$content is now <strike>a simpleDOM object</strike> an array (corrected).

How do I convert that back to XHTML so I just have:

```
<div id="content">
<h2>Section head</h2>
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into string 
$str = $content->save();
```

Reference:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I have corrected my question. $html->find('#content') returns an array NOT an object, so cannot use $content->save();

Answer (score 0):

This worked OK:

```
// Sample HTML string
$html_str = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Head</h1><div class="page"><div id="content"><h2>Section head</h2><p>Text</p></div><div id="footer">Footer text</div></div></body></html>';

// Create new DOM object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// $html_str is HTML (can load from URL, if your host allows)
$dom->loadHTML($html_str);

// Get DIV id="content"
$element = $dom->getElementById('content');

// use save XML as input is XHTML.
echo $dom->saveXML($element);

// cleanup to prevent memory leak
$dom->clear(); 
unset($dom);
```

If using in another template, you will have to add correct charset to display characters properly